# Many-to-Many (M:N) relation for more than 2 tables

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-flow, neoscms

I have 3 tables namely Organization,People,Roles

I want to have many-to-many relation between: Organization, People, Roles

Example:

```
Organization1 - People1 - Roles1
Organization1 - People2 - Roles1
Organization2 - People2 - Roles2
```

In other way

```
Organization1 - User1 - Manager
Organization2 - User1 - Admin
Organization2 - User2 - Salesman
```

Like this I need it.

How do I do it using flow3 ?
Is it possible to Join More than 2 tables in ManytoMany Join ?

Comment: You could create an entity that describes this relation. Something like "RoleAssignment". That way, you could also add an expiry date to the assignment and similar things, giving you more flexibility.

Comment: Could you brief more on this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a new Model for that. Just create one with all default configs and add the three 1-to-n (or n-to-1, depends on your viewing) realtions in it.